# Browser automatic caching vs Javascript manual caching?

Tags: javascript, http, caching, browser

What are the pors and cons of using `cach-control` header caching (native http caching) VS manual caching using Javascript (decide when to request ressource and when to retrieve it from variable or local storage according to some logic) ?

Comment: Among other things: HTTP caching can leverage *proxy caching* (e.g. CDNs).

Comment: Could you elaborate on your definition of *manual caching*? If we do talk about http caching, then only ServiceWorker API allows us to do *manual caching*. Live application memory and browser storage are complete different beasts.

Comment: 2) Reinventing the wheel 3) no tooling support